# When to use crate:: vs proj_name:: in imports?

Tags: rust

I understand that one can import functionality within the project in 3 different ways:

1. Using project name

```
use proj_name::mod1::mod2::fn_name;
```

2. Using `crate`

```
use crate::mod1::mod2::fn_name;
```

3. Using a relative path

```
use mod1::mod2::fn_name;
```

What I'm confused about is that it seems that sometimes the compiler wants me to use (1) and sometimes (2) / (3). I can't figure out the ruleset for which should be used when. Can someone help?

Comment: 1) Is needed when you have both a library crate and one or more binary crates. I.E. if you have both a `lib.rs` and a `main.rs`, you will have to use package_name in `main.rs` and it's children to refer to items defined in `lib.rs` and it's children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the crate itself is allowed to refer to itself as The `crate`. Every single dependant uses its name prefix. That includes binary targets within the same crate. They might be coupled together in the project, but they are NOT part of library crate.

Binary targets in fact are all separate crates for all purposes of the build system that work the same as libraries that have `lib.rs` at their root and writing `crate` in them refers to root of that specific binary target.

---

Demo:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct A;

mod b {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub struct B(pub crate::A);
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", b::B(A));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c0c209bc78ef6d03bbb6b3c93c9edc8d)

Comment: So let me read that back to see if I got it right. Any file that is imported into lib.rs can be referred to by any other file that is also imported into lib.rs by crate::etc. But any file outside of lib.rs needs to import the crate "from the outside" using the crate's name. Is that how it works?

Comment: @ilmoi yes, because they're different crates and separate from eachother.